# Setting color palette in R

Tags: r, colors

I have been trying to produce a plot in just grayscale for the confidence interval fill and black lines for the predicted lines. I have tried every lead I find online and so far it has not produced a plot in grayscale. Much obliged for any help.

For reference, Predictor 1 is a categorical variable (3 levels) and Predictor 2 is a continuous predictor variable.

```
library(ggthemes)
ggplot() +
geom_ribbon(data=yhat, aes(x=Predictor2, ymax=fit+se*1.96, 
ymin=fit-se*1.96, fill=Predictor1), alpha=0.5)+ geom_line(data=yhat,
aes(Predictor2, fit, color=Predictor1), size=1.5)
+xlab('') + ylab('') + ggtitle('')+
theme_few(base_size=14)+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))+
geom_abline(aes(intercept=0.5,slope=0),linetype="dashed")
```

Comment: Have you tried `scale_fill_gradient`?

Comment: You should include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can actually run your code to see what is being produced.

Comment: Perhaps `scale_colour_brewer(palette="Greys")` (resp. `scale_fill...`) or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your own pallette for ggplot

```
pallette_yellow_green <- c("#ffff00", "#d4e100", "#bfd300", "#95b500", "#80a600", "#6a9700", "#558800", "#2b6b00", "#155c00", "#003400")
```

and then

```
 ggplot()+scale_fill_manual(values = pallette_yellow_green)
```

how to find color codes? use for example http://www.colorhexa.com/ (go for gradient generator)

that settles the issue for discrete variable

for continuous variables `scale_fill_continuous` or `scale_fill_gradient` should set you up: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient.html

Comment: Thanks all for the help! Sorry I didn't post the rest of code. I will do so for future questions. drsh1's comment did the trick! Thanks again.

Comment: please mark my answer as correct so I can get reputation boost :)